# Is there away to comment the implementation of function in Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

Iknow there similar questions to this,but I didn't find an answer that can solve my problem, I have Program composed of one Header file, that includes mutiple `static` variables and functions.

the variable are used in mutiple source file, and have then different meaning , the functions too are implementet in different way  in each time . My question is how can my comment in the source file be sees in `HTML` doxygen file. like :

```
/*!<
function that does stuff
@param value representing the mean stuff 
*/

    double func(double* value){
         FILE* inp =NULL; /*!< the file pointer of this function to write the result*/
         .............................................//!* all this commments should be see in functiopn description 
    }
```

and by the I know that , if I open the source file in the documentation I'll see the comment , but I want to explain the roll of each function and how it doing its job!

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock

If you just comment with // it won't appear on doxygen. Doxygen only parses comments starting with certain tokens, such as `/**` or `/*!`

Comment: first I want to thank you for your help, but in my comments I use /*!

Comment: use this way  //! A normal member taking two arguments and returning an integer value.

Comment: sorry  but it shows me the comment but not the vairable in HTML page so I got the explanation  without knowing what the comment is refering to